# Entering different default values in a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In this GUI, the same default value (1) is entered in all four fields. How can I enter four different numbers (e.g. -2.5, 1, -1.5 and 1.5) as the default values instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
fields = ('R1', 'R2', 'I1', 'I2')

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = {}
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=22, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      ent.insert(0,1)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries[field] = ent
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

`fields = ('R1', 'R2', 'I1', 'I2')` to `fields = (('R1',1), ('R2',2), ('I1',3), ('I2',4))`
and use

```
for field, default in fields:
....
ent.insert(0,default)
...
```